# How do I display numbers in the List Box?

Tags: listbox, vb6

**Introduction:** Hi! I'm new in VB6 UI and I just want to make numbers appear in a list box.

**Details:** And what I mean is that, for example, I have two textboxes and the 1st textbox is labeled as "From" and the 2nd "To" and if the user inputs 1 in "From" and 10 in "To", I wanna list numbers 1 to 10 in the List Box.

**What you've tried?:** Don't know what to write right now.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub btCalculate_Click()
    Dim From As Long
    Dim T As Long
    
    From = Val(txtFrom.Text)
    T = Val(txtTo.Text)

End Sub
```

Thank you for answering and replying to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a loop.  Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btCalculate_Click()
   Dim i As Integer
   
   lstCount.Clear
   
   For i = Val(txtFrom.Text) To Val(txtTo.Text)
      lstCount.AddItem i
   Next
End Sub
```

Where `lstCount` is a ListBox.